# cant install or boot from ubuntu 12.10 dvd

Tags: 12.10, boot

I burned two ubuntu 12.10 amd64 images: one from the official site, the other one is [ubuntu secure remix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-secured/files/)

They both did not work because when I hit enter on either "try without installing" or "install ubuntu" the monitor turns into the black screen with a flashing underscore cursor in the top-left corner and freezes.

My computer is an Asus g75vw laptop with i7 processor and gtx 660m.
I am trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 7 pro 64bits.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I have done the checksum by this [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). The sum are the same.

Comment: Have you checked md5sum of your image files?

Answer (score 2):

Hey friend :) u can check this out : [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) . And if it's help u please close this case and give me "up"  :D hahahaha

Comment: Thank you very much. But right now I dont have enough reputations to vote up your answer. I will come back with my vote-up once I gain enough reputations. :D

Comment: Oke Will... i will wait for that :D hahahahaha